# IONIC-3 NavController throwing can't resolve all parameters error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an interesting problem with IONIC-3 that I've not been able to solve. I am attempting to implement an auth routing which is triggered by ionViewCanEnter. However, while I can pass one nav setter, it will not allow multiple. Here is the code:

**AuthService Function:**

```
isAuthenticated(nav: NavController): boolean | Promise<any> {
const userAuth = this.uData.getAuthenticated;
const userProfile = this.uData.getUserProfile;

if (userAuth ) {
  //User is logged in, so let's check a few things.
  if (!userProfile.sign_up_complete) {
    //User has not completed sign up
    setTimeout(() => { nav.setRoot(CreateAccountPage) }, 0);
  }
  return true
} else {
  //User is not authenticated, return to walkthrough
  setTimeout(() => { nav.setRoot(WalkthroughPage) }, 0);
  return false
}}
```

**Example calling:**

```
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean | Promise<any> {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated(this.nav);
}
```

If I have only CreateAccountPage, the script runs fine. However, when I add WalkthroughPage, it throws the following error:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ListingPage: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
```

Which is an error related to the AuthService. For clarity the WalkthroughPage code is as follows:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RemoteConfigProvider } from '../../providers/remote-config/remote-config';

import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'walkthrough-page',
  templateUrl: 'walkthrough.html'
})
export class WalkthroughPage {

  lastSlide = false;

  sign_up_enabled: null;
  sign_in_enabled: null;

  @ViewChild('slider') slider: Slides;

  constructor(public nav: NavController,
    public remoteConfig: RemoteConfigProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.remoteConfig.getValue('sign_up_enabled').then(t => {
      this.sign_up_enabled = t;
    })

    this.remoteConfig.getValue('sign_in_enabled').then(t => {
      this.sign_in_enabled = t;
    })
  }

  skipIntro() {
    this.lastSlide = true;
    this.slider.slideTo(this.slider.length());
  }

  onSlideChanged() {
    this.lastSlide = this.slider.isEnd();
  }

  goToLogin() {
    this.nav.push(LoginPage);
  }

  goToSignup() {
    this.nav.push(SignupPage);
  }
}
```

I have attempted to compare both pages, but not identified the exact cause. I welcome any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter a similar issue, the fix was straight forward. I simply used deep-linking reference which resolved all issues. Example below.

```
isAuthenticated(nav: NavController): boolean | Promise<any> {
        const userAuth = this.userStore.getAuthenticated;
        const userProfile = this.userStore.getUserProfile;
        if (userAuth) {       
          return true
        } else {
          console.log('Auth guard: Not authenticated');
          setTimeout(() => { nav.setRoot('no-access') }, 0);
          return false
        }
      }
```